# Scaling an uneven mesh

Tags: transforms

I want to scale an uneven mesh, the original mesh is highlighted below:
[image]

As you can see, there's additional geometry on the left side, so the median point moved left, not at the center. By using median point as pivot point, the resulting mesh was scaled to the left side, not aligned to the center, like below:
[image]

I know that I can use 3D cursor, which is placed at the center as pivot point, so the mesh after scale is aligned to the center, like below:
[image]

My question is, if I made my mesh like picture 2, how can I fix it, so the mesh is aligned to the center like picture <s>2</s> 3?

Thank you.

Comment: maybe snap to vertice would do the trick if I understand you correctly, you made mistake in last sentence, you used picture 2 twice, I guess one of them was supposed to be 3

Comment: @MikoCG Yes it is a mistake, edited.